# how do I clone files with colons in the filename

Tags: windows, git, filenames

When I clone the repo using msysgit, all the files with spaces in the filename are not brought down, and then show as deleted in the status.

The filenames looks something like this: `styles-ie (1:12:11 6:02 PM).css` so it might actually be the colon or brackets?

How can I fetch those files to bring my local repo inline with the origin?

Comment: according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177506 a colon is an invalid filename character on Windows.  So does this mean that I can never clone/fetch the file to a Windows system or is there some filename translation?

Comment: I suggest you change the file name.

Comment: More accurately, I believe you can't *check out* the file. The object (blob) representing it is in your repository, and it was transferred as part of a clone or fetch, but when Git attempts to write that file into your work tree, Windows won't let it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you try doing:

```
touch "styles-ie (1:12:11 6:02 PM).css"
```

you will see that you cannot create it on Windows.

Basically, the repo has the file ( the blob and the tree entry ) but you cannot checkout on Windows as git would be unable to create such a file. No other way but to change the filename.

Comment: thanks, so specifically a user with a clone of the repo on a non-Windows system needs to change the filename and push so that I can fetch it, right?

Comment: @Jonathan Day - yes that would be the case.

Comment: This answer is correct but if you'd like a workaround keep reading - @RJLyders answer below is amazing useful.

Comment: You could use WSL for this, link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 19):

**Good news.** 
Technically, the answer to "how do I clone files with colons in the filename" is to simply use "git clone". Luckily it is only the checkout that fails on Windows (even under msysgit) and there is a rather clean workaround for this shown below.

***TL;DR***

in Git Bash...

```
git clone {repo URL}
cd {repo dir}
git ls-tree -r master --name-only | grep -v ":" | xargs git reset HEAD
git commit -m "deleting all files with a colon in the name"
git restore .
```

... and then

- download the Zip of the whole git repo
- rename files with colons inside the Zip (without extracting them)
- extract just those files you renamed
- add those renamed files to your working directory

**For insight into those few steps listed above, please keep reading....**

I was able to work around this issue while working with a repo with colons in various filenames. The following worked for me:

- Do a regular git clone.

`$ git clone https://github.com/wdawson/dropwizard-auth-example.git`

You should see the following error that notes that the clone succeeded, but the checkout failed.

```
Cloning into 'dropwizard-auth-example'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 322, done.
remote: Total 322 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 322
Receiving objects: 100% (322/322), 15.00 MiB | 2.88 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (72/72), done.
error: invalid path 'src/test/resources/revoker/example-ca/certs/root.localhost:9000.cert.pem'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

- Change directories to the new cloned repo

`cd dropwizard-auth-example`

- Check that the git repo working directory is completely empty

`ls`

- Run git-status to find that all the files are staged for deletion

`$ git status`

Output...

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    .gitignore
        deleted:    .travis.yml
        deleted:    LICENSE
        deleted:    NOTICE
        deleted:    README.md
        deleted:    conf.yml
...
```

- Revert the staged deletion of *only* the files that do *not* contain a colon in the file name.

`$ git ls-tree -r master --name-only | grep -v ":" | xargs git reset HEAD`

Output...

```
Unstaged changes after reset:
D       .gitignore
D       .travis.yml
D       LICENSE
D       NOTICE
D       README.md
D       conf.yml
D       java-cacerts.jks
D       pom.xml
D       src/main/java/wdawson/samples/dropwizard/UserInfoApplication.java
D       src/main/java/wdawson/samples/dropwizard/api/UserInfo.java
D       src/main/java/wdawson/samples/dropwizard/auth/OAuth2Authenticator.java
D       src/main/java/wdawson/samples/dropwizard/auth/OAuth2Authorizer.java
D       src/main/java/wdawson/samples/dropwizard/auth/Role.java
...
```

- Run git status again to see that only the files that contain a colon in the file name are now staged for deletion. All other files are still showing as deleted, but not staged for commit. This is what we want at this stage.

`$ git status`

Output...

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    src/test/resources/revoker/example-ca/certs/root.localhost:9000.cert.pem
        deleted:    src/test/resources/revoker/example-ca/csr/root.localhost:9000.csr.pem
        deleted:    src/test/resources/revoker/example-ca/intermediate/certs/intermediate.localhost:9000.cert.pem
        deleted:    src/test/resources/revoker/example-ca/intermediate/csr/intermediate.localhost:9000.csr.pem
        deleted:    src/test/resources/revoker/example-ca/intermediate/private/intermediate.localhost:9000.key.pem
        deleted:    src/test/resources/revoker/example-ca/private/root.localhost:9000.key.pem

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    .gitignore
        deleted:    .travis.yml
        deleted:    LICENSE
        deleted:    NOTICE
        deleted:    README.md
        deleted:    conf.yml
        deleted:    java-cacerts.jks
        deleted:    pom.xml
```

- Commit all the staged files. That is, commit the deletion of all the files that contain a colon in the file name.

`git commit -m "deleting all files with a colon in the name"`

- Restore everything in the working directory.

`$ git restore .`

- View all the files. What a beautiful site.

`$ ls`

Output...

`conf.yml  java-cacerts.jks  LICENSE  NOTICE  pom.xml  README.md  src`

Once you've deleted the offending files from your working directory...

- download a Zip of the whole GitHub repo
- open it up in 7Zip... Don't unzip it ... just open it for editing (to rename files)
- find the files that have a colon in the name
- rename each file with a colon replacing the colon with an underscore...or whatever is appropriate
- now you can extract those files you just renamed
- copy them into the git working directory

PS: All of the above was done in GitBash on Windows 10 using git version 2.25.1.windows.1. Similar steps can be done via the GUI using TortoiseGit on Windows.

Answer (score 8):

You can clone the repo on a linux environment, tar it up and copy it to windows, and untar it on windows with tools such as [7zip](http://www.7zip.org). 7zip will replace the colon with underscore, and preserve all the git information. As long as that file does not change, you'll be all set for a while. Those files tend not to change much anyway (for example, I have a cert file with a colon in the middle).

Answer (score 1):

In support to the answers "using WSL" or "using Linux environment":

Using WSL:
(Windows 11)

**1. Enable virtualization:**

- in BIOS
- in Windows (*"Turn Windows features on or off" -> "Virtual Machine Platform"/"Windows Subsystem for Linux"* -> check)

**2. Download and install linux distibutive (e.g. Ubuntu - latest):**

- in PowerShell:

  *wsl --install -d Ubuntu*

**3. Clone repo in WSL linux console**

After WSL has been installed - run the application "WSL" - there going to be a linux console available. In that linux console - clone repository as you would normally do**.

** In my case I logged in as root (>sudo su), created ssh keys, added public ssh key to the github repo, navigated to required directory and cloned ssh repo.

As a result, through WSL console I'm able to see files with ":".
Through another file managers, consoles (File Explorer, PowerShell, cmd, git CLI) - in place of colons different symbols displayed.

Answer (score 0):

### Purly in **Windows**

```
git clone --sparse -c core.protectNTFS=false -n <YOUR REPO>
cd <INTO YOUR REPO'S NEWLY CREATED SUBFOLDER>
git sparse-checkout add \* !\path\to\evil\file:with.colon
git checkout <BRANCH NAME, POTENTIALLY JUST "main">
git rm path\to\evil\file:with.colon
```

Potentially also remove an actually checked out "path\to\evil\file" (a version without colon), commit, push, (now you can already check out the current version on windows), if you need it, create a file with better name.

**Dummy hint:** Replace both `path\to\evil\file:with.colon` with your evil file path, relative to project root (but keep the `!` in front of it, at line 3, e.g. `!/static/icons/some.png:With.Id`).

**Recognition:** Regards to the deleted answer of @RomanOrekhov (while incomplete, it was falsely removed as duplicate for using sparse-checkout, as no answer suggested that obvious route).

Answer (score 0):

To add to RJLyders answer, using `git ls-tree -r main --name-only | grep -v ":" | xargs -I {} git reset HEAD "{}"` will ensure that file paths with spaces will also be preserved.