# Issue with Windows and Git with illegal filenames

Tags: windows, git, perl, file

So, I'm working on a component to my company's project in which we are using git as our version control. After I finished my task on the project, I needed to send my code in for review.

The problem is, **I'm working on a Windows machine** with perl files names on the remote git branch that something similar to **"filename::123.pm"**. So what Windows does when I checkout this branch is just delete them from my local branch, and all file names with a :: in them are gone. Since these are important files, this is an issue for my additions on the local branch and cannot be merged since then the important perl files are gone.

*How do I avoid this?*

I wanted to try something like ignore the specific files for a git clone of the repo, so when I checkout they are ignored anyways and not removed, but this is impossible. Another thing I wanted to do was clone on a VM running linux and work from there to do commits. Well the cloning is super slow, and that isn't an option either.

What is my best option for working with this repo where the filenames are invalid for a Windows machine to read? And no, renaming the files isn't going to work since so there is so much more work to be done if we did that.

Comment: The ":" is a reserved character in filenames on windows, this may give more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991805/how-do-i-clone-files-with-colons-in-the-filename. By the way you can make a shallow clone by adding `--depth 1`on your VM machine, if partial history is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Surely you must use git sparse-checkout feature that permit to checkout only some directories and in your case ignore directories with not supported files.

Example :

http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/

Comment: Great! Never even thought of the possibility of doing a partial checkout like this