# Git bash won't let me pull

Tags: git, bash, github, git-pull

So I made some changes to my file and now when I check my status it says :

```
   On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 80 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So I try to pull and it says

```
error: unable to create file docs/com/teamname/tutortrader/C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt (Invalid argument)
```

I've tried to `git rm -f docs/com/teamname/tutortrader/C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt` but it just says that this file doesn't exist. I've also tried `rm -f C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt`, but that doesn't exist either.

Comment: Looks like one of those 80 remote commits contains a file called "C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt" in the directory "docs/com/teamname/tutortrader". If that's the case, you'll need to fix that before pulling. It may be easiest to get the person who committed that file to fix it.

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn Git status is the first thing on page,

Comment: As Paul says -- your repo contains a file with a name that can't be created on Windows. Get a collaborator to fix it for you, or delete it from the repo through the web interface.

Comment: @PaulHicks Thanks, I thought the git rm -f would do the trick but guess not. That fixed the problem

Comment: `git rm -f` would only work if that file existed in your *local* copy. It's not local, it's in the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the github interface with a file open, look at the top-right-hand side. You'll see buttons labeled "Raw", "Blame" and "History". To their right -- if you have write access to the repo -- there will also be a garbage can. Clicking on that will commit a change deleting that file from the repository.

Do so for the offending file, and you'll again be able to check this out on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Some kind person (presumably on Linux or Mac) has added a file to your repo called `C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt`.  This is an invalid filename on Windows.  You need to get them to rename this file or you won't be able to clone this repo on Windows any more.

c.f. [how do I clone files with colons in the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991805/how-do-i-clone-files-with-colons-in-the-filename)