# Cannot clone a git repository from github

Tags: windows, git, github, clone

I am trying to clone a github repository to my local windows machine url: https://github.com/Patrick-The-Star/codility-lessons.git . But I get this result :

```
Cloning into 'codility-lessons'...
remote: Counting objects: 349, done.
emote: Total 349 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 349
Receiving objects: 100% (349/349), 2.38 MiB | 1.09 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (115/115), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
fatal: cannot create directory at 'lesson 1 : Time Complexity': Invalid argument
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

I researched a little and it seems I need to have enough disk space and I do. I assume it is because of the file name and it has spaces in the file "lesson 1 : Time complexity" I am not sure though. Either way how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Spaces in a file name won't cause any issues with a checkout. What command did you enter to clone the repo? What is the output of git status? The clone itself looks like it was successful, something else appears to be wrong.

Comment: the colon in the name is the problem.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#file_and_directory_names

Comment: @murtuza any idea how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

[how do I clone files with colons in the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991805/how-do-i-clone-files-with-colons-in-the-filename)

basically you can't clone this repository on windows.  You need to change the names of the folders or use an OS that allows colons in filenames, i.e. not windows

EDIT: I forked the repository and changed the colons to dashes.  you should be able to clone this: https://github.com/prettyClouds/codility-lessons

Answer (score 0):

If you use a 64-Bit version of Windows 10, you can use the experimental Linux Subsystem. Here's a decent summary..
[How to install and use the Linux Bash-shell on Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

Then you can access them with powershell/cmd (if you change the filenames) or work with them in 'bash-shell'.