# Git failed to check-out code in windows cmd

Tags: windows, git, github, git-clone, git-checkout

So I'm trying to do a git clone in windows CMD. But I end-up with following error. I tried every work around. But had no luck.

```
Cloning into 'tomato-api'...
remote: Counting objects: 67887, done.
remote: Total 17346 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 17346
Receiving objects: 100% (67887/67887), 643.56 MiB | 742.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7654/7654), done.
fatal: cannot create directory at 'vegitables/market/github.com/docker/distribution/sharing/united-streets/generated_certs.d/localregistry:5440': Invalid argument
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Comment: Please check the permission of the folder where you try to take checkout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I clone files with colons in the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991805/how-do-i-clone-files-with-colons-in-the-filename)

Answer (score 1):

The git repository you are trying to clone from has a directory with path consisting of the Windows reserved word - colon (`:`). Therefore, that directory is not able to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach [more recently discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75120947/6309) is to:

- [git clone --no-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--n) the repository
- delete all files with '`:`' in their name (same for [files with `\` in their name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75197873/6309))

Using [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), you can remove them from the full history of the repository.