# Remove all files from Git repo history with path having escape \ in filename with git filter-repo

Tags: git, git-checkout, backslash, invalid-characters, git-history

I have special filenames with escape \ characters stored in Git repository on Debian 10 Linux.

Problem: it is not possible to git checkout files on Windows, which have incompatible characters in the filename.

**Example:**

```
git log --all --name-only -m --pretty= '*\\*'
"systemd/system/default.target.wants/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"
"systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"
"systemd/system/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"
```

I get following Git errors at Windows checkout:

```
C:\Git\bin\git.exe reset --hard "5ef1cac3a03304c35b455edf32bd1bb78060c5b9" --
error: invalid path 'systemd/system/default.target.wants/snap-git\x2dfilter\x2drepo-7.mount'
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision '5ef1cac3a03304c35b455edf32bd1bb78060c5b9'.
Done
```

**Problem reproducing steps:**

```
# Clone repository, to be executed on a safe repo:
git clone --no-local /source/repo/path/ /target/path/to/repo/clone/
# Cloning into '/target/path/to/repo/clone'...
# remote: Enumerating objects: 9534, done.
# remote: Counting objects: 100% (9534/9534), done.
# remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4776/4776), done.
# remote: Total 9534 (delta 4215), reused 8043 (delta 3136), pack-reused 0
# Receiving objects: 100% (9534/9534), 7.41 MiB | 16.78 MiB/s, done.
# Resolving deltas: 100% (4215/4215), done.

cd /target/path/to/repo/clone/

# List the files with escape \ from repo history into a list file:
git log --all --name-only -m --pretty= '*\\*' | sort -u >/opt/git_repo_files_w_escape.txt

# Remove the files with escape \ from repo history:
git filter-repo --invert-paths --paths-from-file /opt/git_repo_files_w_escape.txt
Parsed 592 commits
New history written in 0.25 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
HEAD is now at 71128f3 .gitignore: ADD snap-git to be ignored
Enumerating objects: 9354, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9354/9354), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3694/3694), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9354/9354), done.
Total 9354 (delta 4085), reused 9354 (delta 4085), pack-reused 0
Completely finished after 0.55 seconds.


# List files with escape \ to check result:
git log --format="reference" --name-status --diff-filter=A '*\\*'
# "systemd/system/default.target.wants/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"
# "systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"
# "systemd/system/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"

#  Unfortunately it seems filter-repo was executed, but log still lists filenames with escape \ :-(
```

**Question:**

**1) How to remove all files from Git repo history with path having at least one escape \ character in filename?**

(reason: it is not possible to checkout those files on Windows, which have incompatible characters in the filename)

**UPDATE1:**

Tried to replace `\\x2d` string to - in input file list as suggested, but git history remove was still unsuccessful:

```
# List the files with escape \ from repo history into a list file:
git log --all --name-only -m --pretty= '*\\*' | sort -u >/opt/git_repo_files_w_escape.txt

# Replace \\x2d string to - in git_repo_files_w_escape.txt:
sed -i 's/\\\\x2d/-/g' /opt/git_repo_files_w_escape.txt

# Remove the listed files from repo history:
git filter-repo --invert-paths --paths-from-file /opt/git_repo_files_w_escape.txt
Parsed 592 commits
New history written in 0.25 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
HEAD is now at 71128f3 .gitignore: ADD snap-git to be ignored
Enumerating objects: 9354, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9354/9354), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3694/3694), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9354/9354), done.
Total 9354 (delta 4085), reused 9354 (delta 4085), pack-reused 0
Completely finished after 0.55 seconds.


# List files with escape \ to check result:
git log --format="reference" --name-status --diff-filter=A '*\\*'
# "systemd/system/default.target.wants/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"
# "systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"
# "systemd/system/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"

#  Unfortunately log still lists filenames with \\x2d :-(
```

**UPDATE2:**

Tried to replace `\\x2d` in git_repo_files_w_escape.txt to `\\\\x2d` or `\x2d` but none of them resulted to remove the files having `\\x2d` in filename from Git history.

**UPDATE3:**

**I'm looking for a working solution based on git filter-repo.**

Any more idea?

Comment: Colon is not backslash so what are we even talking about here?

Comment: And otherwise isn't this the same as your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75112545/how-to-remove-all-files-from-git-repo-history-with-path-having-colon-in-filena ?

Comment: Colon was a typo. Fixed in OP.

Comment: Also backslash of itself is not escape character. It's just a backslash.

Comment: Well in Linux bash you have to escape special chars in path with backslash. So it is escape char.

Comment: But that doesn't make the escape backslash a character in the resulting path. It's just a way of talking to bash.

Comment: Not the same as [#75112545](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75112545/how-to-remove-all-files-from-git-repo-history-with-path-having-colon-in-filena), because the working solution used in  #75112545 for colon, does not work for backslash. So it requires opening a new question.

Comment: Only if one doesn't understand string escaping, perhaps. Otherwise they are identical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251219/discussion-between-klor-and-matt).

Comment: Basically, you are just trying to figure out how to escape a [unicode minus sign](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) in a path in Windows.

Comment: @JDB No. I try to remove files with invalid characters in filename from GIT repo history.

Comment: @klor - I think that `\\x2d` is an escape sequence which is translated to `-`. I bet you could make your code work if you changed your paths to `systemd/system/default.target.wants/snap-git-filter-repo-7.mount`, etc.

Comment: @JDB Good idea. Almost sure this is the problem source. I will try this immediately.

Comment: @JDB Unfortunately not. Edited file with git_repo_files_w_escape.txt, replaced \\x2d with -  and executed `git filter-repo`. After listing git log, the files are still there.

Comment: Did you try 4 slashes, for testings? `\\\\x2d`.

Comment: @VonC Yes. See the updated OP. `sed -i 's/\\\\x2d/-/g' /opt/git_repo_files_w_escape.txt`

Comment: @klor Sorry, I meant keeping the `\x2d` in the file (so no sed, no replacement by '-'), but using in that file `\\x2d` (2 slash) or `\\\\x2d` (4 slash) for testing. Again, no sed, edit the file directly.

Comment: @VonC Both were unsuccessful, `\\x2drepo-7.mount` and `\\\\x2drepo-7.mount`, too :-(

Comment: Does it have to be a `git-filter-repo` solution, or is the important aspect that you need to change the whole history regardless of the tool used?

Comment: @j6t Well, history rewriting is a risky task. `git filter-branch` became obsoleted, because `git filter-repo` does the same task safer and faster. This is the reason I stick to `git filter-repo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fed bad input into filter-repo, based on a common but incorrect assumption about how git log works.

Look at your own output:

```
$ git log --format="reference" --name-status --diff-filter=A '*\\*'
"systemd/system/default.target.wants/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"
"systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"
"systemd/system/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"
```

Let's look at the first line as an example. If you were to store that in a file, which you pass to --paths-from-file, then git-filter-repo is going to be looking for a file named `"systemd/system/default.target.wants/snap-git\\x2dfilter\\x2drepo-7.mount"` to remove. You have no such file in your repository. Instead you have one named `systemd/system/default.target.wants/snap-git\x2dfilter\x2drepo-7.mount`. (Note that I have removed both `"` characters and two of the `\` characters.)

The problem here is that you assumed git log would list filenames as-is, which it won't do whenever there are special characters. You can often get around this by setting core.quotepath=false (this particularly helps when you have non-ascii characters), but even that is ignored when you have backslashes.

Here's something that might work better for you for generating the list of filenames to exclude:

```
git log -z --all --name-only -m --pretty= '*\\*' | tr '\0' '\n' | sort -u >/opt/git_repo_files_w_escape.txt
```

but it assumes you do not have filenames with newline characters. (If you do have files with newline characters, though, then --paths-from-file won't work for you.)

Even simpler would be bypassing creating a list of files with bad names and just programatically removing them by pattern:

```
git filter-repo --filename-callback 'return None if b'\\' in filename else filename'
```

Comment: @newren Thank you very much for pointing me to the right solution!
Your solution works perfectly, it removed all files having backlash in filename.
You are right, it is not a bug, just the git log result was not in the right format for input into `git filter-repo`.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, this worked on a linux system, this allowed me to rewrite the HEAD commit without having the files checked out on disk:

```
git ls-files | grep -a -e '\\' | while read f; do
    f=$(echo $f | sed -e 's|"||g')
    new=$(echo "$f" | sed -e 's|\\\\x2d|-|g')
    git show "@:$f" > $new
    git rm --cached "$f"
    git add "$new"
done

git status
git commit --amend
```

The same commands should work on `git-bash` for windows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this answer rewrites only the HEAD, not the whole repo history. I'm looking for a working solution based on git filter-repo.

Comment: @klor: if you take the command as is, yes. It also provides a base for writing a set of commands that renames files containing '\\' in their names, which could give you a way to turn it into a script which you can invoke with `git filter-branch` for example. Unfortunately I don't have enough time to research a complete solution to your issue.

Comment: also check https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_filtering_based_on_many_paths

Comment: perhaps fiddling with something like `regex:(.*)(\\\\x2d)(.*)=>\1-\3` (try it on a smaller repo to check the effects)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have many files that you want to fix scattered in the hierarchy, a solution with `git filter-repo` looks tedious. You can instead use a combination of `git fast-export` and `git fast-import` to modify file names in the whole history.

```
git fast-export --no-data --all > exported
```

Now delete the file entries containing a backslash:

```
grep -v '^[DM] .*\\' exported > fixed
```

Instead of removing the files, you can also modify the file names. For example, to replace the backslash by a dash `-`, you could try this:

```
sed -e '/^[DM] /s,\\,-,g' < exported > fixed
```

You may now investigate the difference between the two files to ensure that no commit messages were modified:

```
diff -u exported fixed | less
```

Now attempt to import the modified history:

```
git fast-import < fixed
```

This will stop with an error that tells you that the branches will not be modified because the old branch heads are not subsets of the new heads. If there are no other errors, you can now force the modification:

```
git fast-import --force < fixed
```

Comment: Nah, not tedious at all with filter-repo.  But, more importantly, suggesting programmatic edits of fast-export should be accompanied with big warnings.  The `--no-data` avoids the worst problems, but you should really emphasize how important that option is to avoid folks modifying your solution for other problems where they drop that option and then corrupt their repo.  Also, even with --no-data, there's a risk that you will be removing lines from commit messages and corrupting the stream.  filter-repo was written in part because editing fast-export streams programatically can be risky.