# how to clone a git repository which has files with ">" symbol in the file name

Tags: git, github, git-clone

The previous team created code in a bizzare naming convention. I'm looking to clone a git repository which has files with ">" symbol in the file name. Ex: "Data>1234.ipynb", "Data>5678.ipynb" etc. There are numerous files like that in the repository. It throws an error when I try to download the repo in a zip format or when I try to use "git clone". Please suggest me a best way to download the repo and reuse.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Post the error you are getting when you tried to git clone the repo

Comment: What operating system are you using? I'm guessing Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I clone files with colons in the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991805/how-do-i-clone-files-with-colons-in-the-filename)

Answer (score 0):

You would use WSL and clone the repo in linux. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10