# Github issue with cloning project

Tags: java, git, github

I have this repo that I was trying to clone into eclipse. It looks like this.
[image]

However, when I run git clone 'git url for repo', it just says this and I do not see any folder created in eclipse. I see an empty folder created on the location on my laptop but that is it. I do not see the contents from the GitHub repo at all. What might be the issue that I might be facing? Thanks in advance.

Please let me know if this is not clear.

[image]

**UPDATE:** I can clone without errors as suggested by someone in the comments. However, when I still clone I get an empty folder without any contents.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are these tab links? Is `Screen Shot 2020-11-08 at 9.53.58 PM.png` a file or some kind of link?

Comment: also I am just interested in the folder, bestbooks_eclipse. I do not really want the rest of it

Comment: @LinFelix yes they are screenshots another contributor uploaded

Comment: Also, there is a `:` (colon) in the path. On windows systems, this is a reserved character.

Comment: Windows is not able to have files containing a colon different than Linux. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991805/how-do-i-clone-files-with-colons-in-the-filename